# How to get Site Icon to properly update in Sharepoint 2010 Web Part Page

Tags: sharepoint, master-pages, webpartpage

I'm working on creating a reusable and extensible web application in SharePoint 2010. I've created a master page to apply across all pages in the site. However, whenever I create a web part page and navigate to it, the site icon does not display. Instead of my custom site icon being displayed it shows the default SharePoint icon. I can get around this by placing the icon directly into the master page, but that would require me to create a new master page if I ever wanted to extend this web application.

Does anyone know why this is happening? My initial thought was that the web part page had somehow been customized to not use the default master page, but that does not seem to be the case: if I update the master page it is reflected in the web part page.

Googling around and checking this site yielded little answers. I only found one post out there that reported the same issue I am observing but there was no solution.

If it helps, I did notice one phenomena when navigating to this page. Before the page completely loads, the correct site icon appears for a split second before being replaced with the default site icon. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue this morning and didn't want to create a custom master page just for this, but luckily it was quickly resolved by following admlcrunch's suggestion (on SharePoint 2010):

1. Go to the desire page
2. Click on the "Page" tab at the top
3. Click on the "Title Bar Properties" at the right (in the ribbon)
4. In the Image Link section on the right, paste in the image URL
5. Click OK

The only bad thing about this is, you have to update every Web Part page that you want custom icon image to display.

Answer (score 2):

I was just having the same issue.  Web Part Pages have their own icon that you can set.

To set the icon click *Page* > *Title Bar Properties*.  This will open the *Web Part Page Title Bar* dialog.  In this dialog there is an area to set the *Image Link*. You can set the icon here.  I just copied the URL to the site icon.

Answer (score 0):

Open the page in designer and remove the custom titlebar place holder:

`[WebPartPages:TitleBarWebPart]`

from the :

`[asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea"]`